# Matching optional numbers in regex

Tags: python, regex

This one is probably a simple one, but I could not find an example that's simple enough to understand (sorry, I'm new with RegEx).

I'm writing some Python code to search for any string that matches any of the following examples:

```
float[20]
float[7532]
float[]
```

So this is what I have so far:

```
import re
p = re.compile('float\[[0-9]+\]')
print p.match("float[20]")
print p.match("float[7532]")
print p.match("float[]")
```

The code works great for the first and second scenarios, but not the third (no numbers between brackets). What's the best way to add that condition?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p = re.compile('float\[[0-9]*\]')
```

putting a * after the character class means 0 or matches of the character class.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
float\[\d*\]
```

\d is a shortcut for [0-9].
The asterisk matches 0..n (any number) of characters of the character class.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator requires at least one instance of whatever it's applying to, which your third option doesn't have.  You want the `*` operator which is 0 or more.  So:

```
p = re.compile('float\[[0-9]*\]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re
p = re.compile('float\[[0-9]*\]')
print p.match("float[20]")
print p.match("float[7532]")
print p.match("float[]")
```

`+` is for one or more elements and `*` is used for zero or more element.